# Get-LocalGroup cmdlet Get-LocalGroup : The term 'Get-LocalGroup' is not recognized as the name of a cmdlet,

Tags: powershell, windows-8

I know that `Get-LocalGroup` cmdlet is in the `Microsoft.PowerShell.LocalAccounts` module. I tried to import that module using the command

```
Get-Module Microsoft.Powershell.LocalAccounts
```

No error after the command is executed, but when I type `Get-Module` to see list of modules loaded into my current session, I don't see a module `Microsoft.Powershell.LocalAccounts` loaded.

Not sure what to do to load that module so that I can use the `Get-LocalGroups` cmdlet.

Comment: The Local Group and User cmdlets are only available in Win10 1607 and later. What version of Windows are you using?

Comment: Ben, I am using Windows 8 version.

Comment: You won't be able to use those cmdlets then. You can use `net.exe localgroup`, ADSI on the WinNT drive, or WMI Win32_Group* classes. But the cmdlet won't work. [This article gives details on some of the way you can accomplish this](https://www.petri.com/use-powershell-to-find-local-groups-and-members)

Comment: Thanks much Ben.

Answer (score 7):

I'm finding that the x86 version of PowerShell is unable to see the LocalAccounts module.

The solution is to run the x64 version of PowerShell (which is the one marked with neither x86 nor x64).

Answer (score 2):

You need to use `Import-Module Microsoft.Powershell.LocalAccounts` to import a module. `Get-Module` does not import modules.

```
PS C:\> Import-Module Microsoft.Powershell.LocalAccounts

PS C:\> Get-Module

ModuleType Version    Name                                ExportedCommands                                                                                                                                                     
---------- -------    ----                                ----------------                                                                                                                                                     
Script     1.0.0.0    ISE                                 {Get-IseSnippet, Import-IseSnippet, New-IseSnippet}                                                                                                                  
Binary     1.0.0.0    Microsoft.Powershell.LocalAccounts  {Add-LocalGroupMember, Disable-LocalUser, Enable-LocalUser, Get-LocalGroup...}                                                                                       
Manifest   3.1.0.0    Microsoft.PowerShell.Management     {Add-Computer, Add-Content, Checkpoint-Computer, Clear-Content...}                                                                                                   
Manifest   3.0.0.0    Microsoft.PowerShell.Security       {ConvertFrom-SecureString, ConvertTo-SecureString, Get-Acl, Get-AuthenticodeSignature...}                                                                            
Manifest   3.1.0.0    Microsoft.PowerShell.Utility        {Add-Member, Add-Type, Clear-Variable, Compare-Object...}                                                                                                            
Manifest   3.0.0.0    Microsoft.WSMan.Management          {Connect-WSMan, Disable-WSManCredSSP, Disconnect-WSMan, Enable-WSManCredSSP...}
```

Comment: I did that . But I get the following error:                                            Import-Module : The specified module 'Microsoft.Powershell.LocalAccounts' was not loaded because no val
was found in any module directory.
At line:1 char:1
+ Import-Module Microsoft.Powershell.LocalAccounts
+ ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : ResourceUnavailable: (Microsoft.Powershell.LocalAccounts:String) [Import-
   tFoundException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : Modules_ModuleNotFound,Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.ImportModuleCommand

Comment: @Jason I think it would also be a good idea to clarify that PowerShell 3+ for installed modules don't have to be imported as they will be dynamically imported if the function/cmdlet is called that was in the exported commands list of the .psd1. The real issue that the asker is having is that the module isn't available on the version of Windows that's being used. So it isn't dynamically imported because it's not installed at all.

Comment: @BenH That's good to know. I hadn't realized that difference for the import.